# FileNotFound error when running spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, bitnami

I am trying to run the `spark-submit` command on my Hadoop cluster
Here is a summary of my Hadoop Cluster:

- The cluster is built using 5 VirtualBox VM's connected on an internal network
- There is 1 namenode and 4 datanodes created.
- All the VM's were built from the Bitnami Hadoop Stack VirtualBox image

When I run the following command:

`spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi $SPARK_HOME/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.0.3.jar 10`

I receive the following error:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/bitnami/sparkStaging/bitnami/.sparkStaging/application_1658417340986_0002/__spark_conf__.zip does not exist`

I also get a similar error when trying to create a sparkSession using PySpark:

`spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('appName').getOrCreate()`

I have tried/verified the following

- environment variables: `HADOOP_HOME`, `SPARK_HOME` AND `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` have been set in my `.bashrc` file
- `SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH` and `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` have been defined in `spark-env.sh`
- Added `spark.master yarn`, `spark.yarn.stagingDir file:///home/bitnami/sparkStaging` and  `spark.yarn.jars file:///opt/bitnami/hadoop/spark/jars/` in `spark-defaults.conf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `spark.yarn.stagingDir`  needs to be an HDFS path.

More specifically, the "YARN Staging directory" needs to be available on all Spark executors, not just a local file path from where you run `spark-submit`

The path that isn't found is being reported from the YARN cluster, where `/home/bitnami` might not exist, or the Unix user running the Spark executor containers does not have access to that path.

Similarly, `spark.yarn.jars` (or `spark.yarn.archive`) should be HDFS paths because these will get downloaded, in parallel, across all executors.

Comment: This resolved the error that I was getting. However, I am now getting a different error message:  ```Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher```. I have updated my question with more details.

Comment: Since this answer solved your original question, please accept it, then create a new post for new errors that you get. Your new error seems related to a separate classpath issue.

Comment: Ultimately, unless you are set on using YARN on bare VMs, I would try to use Bitnami's Helm Charts to deploy Spark on k8s instead and maybe also Hadoop Ozone

Answer (score 0):

Since the spark job is supposed to be submitted to the Hadoop cluster managed by YARN, `master` and `deploy-mode` has to be set. From the [spark 3.3.0 docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit):

```
# Run on a YARN cluster in cluster deploy mode
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=XXX
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master yarn \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --executor-memory 20G \
  --num-executors 50 \
  /path/to/examples.jar \
  1000
```

Or programatically:

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder().appName('appName').master("yarn").config("spark.submit.deployMode","cluster").getOrCreate()
```

Comment: The python script gives the following error: ```Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cluster deploy mode is not applicable to Spark shells.``` , running through ```spark-submit``` just gives the same ```FileNotFoundException```

Comment: @KarthikSankaran, could you try running again by removing the `deploy-mode` line?

Comment: I've removed ```deploy-mode``` in the python code and in spark-submit, but I'm getting the same errors. Also, in python, the FileNotFound error appears below the ```deploy mode is not applicable``` error.

Comment: I think my answer is wrong, please check @OneCricketeer's answer. If it solves your problem, I'll be deleting this answer as it is not useful to anyone.